# filtrar datagridview por varios criterios

Tags: c#, gridview

tengo un textbox que filtra un data grid view funciona correctamente pero quisiera meter un criterio mas en otro textbox que filtre 3 columnas al mismo tiempo

en el textbox que funciona es el que dice figura hace referencia a la columna que dice producto y la filtra correctamente en la funcion esa columna se llama  hclitm

HCCPIL,HCCITM,HCAITM son tres campos en los que se puede encontrar la palabra inv y mediante un textbox quiero filtrar pora esas tres columnas

cabe mencionar que este filtro seria adicional al que ya se hace por hclitm(figura)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi funcion:

```
private void txtFigura_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =
        string.Format("HCLITM LIKE '{0}%' OR HCLITM LIKE '% {0}%'", txtFigura.Text);



    }
```

Comment: Por favor [edit] tu pregunta. ¿Cuáles son las columnas por las que debe filtrar al agregar información en el TextBox `txtFigura`?, ¿Cómo se llaman esas columnas en base de datos?. Debes proporcionar información completa en tu pregunta para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: listo ya lo he editado

Comment: Yo te recomiendo que busques el control Advanced DataGridView, búscalo, es muy bueno y gratuito, y te agrega filtros tipo excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes asignar el mismo método a ambos `TextBox` donde se creará la condición dependiendo del contenido de estos. (reemplaza `txtNuevo` por tu `TextBox` que filtrará)

```
    private void Form_load()
    {
        //Asignar evento a ambos textbox
        txtCalle.TextChanged += Filtrar;
        txtNuevo.TextChanged += Filtrar;
    }
    private void Filtrar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filter = ""; //Se acomulará la condición
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFigura.Text))
        {
            filter += string.Format("HCLITM LIKE '{0}%' OR HCLITM LIKE '% {0}%'", txtFigura.Text); //Filtro que ya tienes
            filter += !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNuevo.Text) ? " OR " : ""; //Agrega un OR en caso de que el sig, TextBox no esté vacío
        }                
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNuevo.Text))
            filter += string.Format("HCCPIL LIKE '%{0}%' OR HCCITM LIKE '%{0}%' OR HCAITM LIKE '%{0}%'", txtNuevo.Text); //Condicón para filtrar las tres columnas

        (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;            
    }
```

Comment: +1, pero yo recomendaría usar los corchetes de apertura y cierre a los if's `así estos tenga una sola línea` - *(creo que es mas por legibilidad que por otra cosa)*.

Comment: muy buena respuesta me sirvio mucho , aunque por ahorita por cuestiones de rapides implemente esto:

(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =
            string.Format("HCLITM LIKE '{0}%' OR HCCPIL LIKE '%{0}%' OR HCCPIL LIKE '{0}%' OR HCCITM LIKE '{0}%'  OR HCCITM LIKE '%{0}%' OR HCAITM LIKE '{0}%' OR HCAITM LIKE '%{0}%'", txtFigura.Text);

me funciono bien , lo unico que no se si es normal es que me pide poner {0}% y luego %{0}% para la misma variable, igual es algo simple pero es la primera ves que uso esto aun soy muy noob

Comment: Es parecido a consultas sql
`Ej. "texto de prueba"`

`LIKE 'de%'` => false, Aqui indicas que la palabra "de" debe estar al comienzo.
`LIKE '%de'` => false, Aqui indicas que la palabra "de" debe estar al final.
`LIKE '%de%'` => true, No importa es que posición este, si la frase contiene "de" es verdadero.

En pocas palabras dado a tu pregunta, solo necesitarías `LIKE '%{0}%'`

Answer (score 0):

Técnicamente puedes incluir cuantos filtros quieras agregado a la cadena del filter cada campo a través de `{0}` estamos incluyendo que valores agregar, así si quieres agregar mas campos por cada campo agregaras **`...{0},..{1},.. {2}`** y como siguientes parámetros podrás agregar los controles que servirán como filtro en el orden del filter para mantener la correspondencia, esta opción es útil cuando se trata de filtrar dos a tres criterios.

Les dejo un ejemplo de la idea:

```
 dwFiltro.RowFilter = string.Format("Convert(Campo1,'System.String') like '%{0}%' and 
                                     Convert(Campo2,'System.String') like '%{1}%' and 
                                     Convert(Campo3,'System.String') like '%{2}%' and 
                                     Convert(Campo4,'System.String') like '%{3}%' ", 
                      control1.Text,control2.Text,control3.Text, control4);
```

Por cierto puedas usar `or` o `and`, todo depende del criterio de los filtros a aplicar...

Saludos.